# why must provide different images for different screen densities?

Tags: android

Why developers must provide different images for different screen densities (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi) ?

Why don't we just provide one big image for big density (e.g. hdpi or xhdpi) ?

Comment: Actually it's not necessary, you can place the same picture or its reference in all four drawing-* folders and it'd be rendered on all types of screens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of reasons why you might want to do this:

- Resizing on the fly takes resources (CPU/memory) and thus slows your app
- You might not be satisfied with resizing algorithm or know how to resize your image to get better end result (think of the case when you have vectors for your image)
- you might want to use different image for different densisies at all (think of the case when your image contain text. You might want to ommit text on low density image if there is not enough space to show it)

Answer (score 1):

If you do provide big images android will have to scale them wish isn't really optimal because it will **waste energy** and **slow your app**.